# How can I convert a string list to a list of ints?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have a string: `line = "[1, 2, 12]\n"`
and I want to convert it to a list of ints: `[1, 2, 12]`

I have the solution:

```
new_list = []
for char in line:
    try:
        new_list.append(int(char))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

But this doesn't work in the case of numbers with more than one digit. Is there an inbuilt/better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_list = [int(num) for num in line.strip('[]\n').split(', ')]
```

A more readable solution will be:

```
line = line.strip('[]\n')
list_of_strs = line.split(', ')
list_of_nums = []
for elem in list_of_strs:
   list_of_nums.append(int(elem))
```

First `line` is stripped of the enclosing brackets and newline characters. Then the remaining string is split on commas and the result is saved in a list. Now we have a list of elements where each number is still a string. Then the `for` loop converts each of the string element into numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re
line = "[1, 2, 12]\n"
new_list = []
for char in re.findall("\d+", line):
    try:
        new_list.append(int(char))
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(new_list)
```

result: `[1, 2, 12]`.

Comment: This is the same `regex` I used! But it returns the `ints` as `strings` so you can easily convert them in a one-line list comprehension. There is no need for a `try, except` statement as you are not having the same issue that the OP was having. The for loop is not looping through `chars` in the original `string`, it is looping through the result of the `regex` so there is no need to test if it can be converted to an int as your `regex` will only return `ints`. :)

Comment: @JoeIddon Yes, you have nice lambda.

Answer (score 0):

## Regex and list comprehension:

The regex: `\d+` will one or more repetitions (`+`) or the previous `RE` so in this case a `digit` (`\d`). So, we can use this on your string by finding all matches for this with `re.findall()`.

However, this will return a `list` of the `ints`: `1`, `2` and `12` but as strings so we can use a list comprehension to convert these into the type `int`.

Your code could look something like this:

```
import re

s = "[1, 2, 12]\n"

l = [int(i) for i in re.findall("\d+", s)]

print(l)
```

This will give the list: `[1, 2, 12]`